# htaccess rewriting URLs with multiple forward slashes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to work out a set of .htaccess mod_rewrite rules that will set these links:

```
domain.com/content-page
domain.com/region/another-page
domain.com/region/brand/more-content-here
```

to fetch files:

```
domain.com/content-page.php
domain.com/region-another-page.php
domain.com/region-brand-more-content-here.php
```

Where 'region' and 'brand' and the page name are all variable/changeable.

So far I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,C]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1-$2 [NC,L]
```

This works but only for one forward slash. As mentioned above, URLs after the domain may have none, one or two forward slashes. Haven't had any luck trying to extend this to deal with multiple (or not) slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# pass through root
RewriteRUle ^(index\.php)?$ - [L]

# no more / so add extension
RewriteCond $1 !/
RewriteCond $1 !\.php$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILEAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: One question -- everything works fine except that 'domain.com' and domain.com/' fail to resolve to the index page now. I get a 404. I'd like any call to the root domain to fetch 'index.php' without showing it in the URL.

Comment: @Dodo try adding a `DirectoryIndex index.php` or `FallbackResource index.php`

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately that doesn't work. Without the Rewrite rules the index page resolves fine for the domain root. Something in there is messing with the ability of the root domain to resolve the index file...

Comment: @Dodo try having a pass-through rule at the top then

Comment: the pass through rule works perfectly. Many thanks for your expertise!