# htaccess remove .php extension from URLs with multiple forward slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to 301 redirect all URLs ending in .php to the non extension version. But the rewrite rules need to work with the existing ones below.

```
# ==== REWRITE URLS ====
RewriteEngine On
# pass through root
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|Sitemap\.xml)?$ - [L]
# no more / so add extension
RewriteCond $1 !/
RewriteCond $1 !\.php$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(_assets|_css|_fonts|_includes|_scripts)($|/) - [L] #exclude these folders using the 'last: L' flag
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L]
```

This is an extension of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059280/htaccess-rewriting-urls-with-multiple-forward-slashes).

So the desired result is:

```
domain.com/region/brand/more-content-here.php
```

Redirects permanently to:

```
domain.com/region/brand/more-content-here
```

But fetches the actual file at:

```
domain.com/region-brand-more-content-here.php
```

Tried a few various ideas but they didn't seem to work in with the existing rules and htaccess is not my strength. Also need it to be querystring friendly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the .php extension ,you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)Permanently redirect "foo.php" to "/foo"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R=301]
#2)Rewrite "/foo" to "/foo.php"#
#this will internally redirect file to file.php#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. All I needed was step #1 as #2 is already covered in the existing rules.

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```